Verwendung von Singular und Plural bei Quantitäten in Bruchform
Meine Frage ist motiviert durch Why is "Null" Plural?
"Eins" is das einzige Zahlwort, das mit Singular verwendet wird:

Null Sekunden
Eine Stunde
Zwei Jahre

Bei nicht-ganzzahligen Quantitäten richtet sich der Sprachgebrauch danach, ob Brüche oder Dezimalzahlen verwendet werden:

eine halbe Minute / 0,5 Minuten
eine viertel Stunde / 0,25 Stunden
eine drei viertel Stunde / 0,75 Stunden

Beide Formen drücken denselben Sachverhalt aus - einmal unter Verwendung des Singular, einmal mit Plural.
In den obigen Beispielen liegen die Werte zwischen 0 und 1. Bei größeren Werten scheint generell der Plural verwendet zu werden:

eineinhalb Stunden / 1,5 Stunden

Es ist offensichtlich, dass Dezimalzahlen immer den Plural nach sich ziehen (auch z.B. 1,0 Stunden).
Gibt es eine offizielle Regel für Brüche?

Ich würde auch "ein und eine halbe Stunde" für richtig halten.

Ich meine es heißt "eine Viertelstunde", nicht "eine viertel Stunde". Ebenso "eine Dreiviertelstunde", "eine Achtelsekunde" usw.

@Raketenolli Okay, aber z.B. ein viertel Stück Kuchen.

Zunächst die Regel für (Dezimal-)Zahlen, die einfacher ist, als man glauben würde:

"eins" ist Einzahl, alles andere Mehrzahl

Unter "alles andere" fällt nicht nur jeder größere Wert, sondern fallen auch alle kleineren Werte.*) Diese kleineren Werte umfallen auch die Null - selbst negative Werte:

Das Triebwerk zündet in einer Minute.
Wir haben minus eins Minuten bis Zündung.

Bei Brüchen ist die Sache auch relativ übersichtlich: der Nenner des Bruches wird als "Einheit" betrachtet und deshalb nicht in den Plural dekliniert. "7/4" sind "sieben Viertel" genau so, wie es auch "sieben Kilo" (und nicht "Kilos" oder "Vierteln") sind.**) Generell haben Einheiten nämlich gar keinen - zumindest keinen wahrnehmbaren - Plural. Das war bei historischen Einheiten anders: "eine Elle, zwei Ellen". Der Zähler hingegen legt Singular oder Plural fest und da gilt wieder das oben Gesagte: "eins" ist Singular, alles andere Plural:

1/4 - das ist ein (Singular wegen "eins") Viertel (Einheit)
2/4 - das sind zwei (Plural wegen "zwei") Viertel (Einheit)

Soweit die Grundregeln. Bei Zeitangaben ist das ein wenig komplizerter, weil die Einheiten bei Zeitangaben sehr wohl einen Plural haben. Meine Vermutung ist, daß diese Einheiten, insbesondere "Stunde", "Minute" und "Sekunde", schon so alt sind und so sehr in den "allgemeinen Gebrauch" übergegangen sind, daß die Sprachentwicklung sie "miterfaßt" hat und sie nicht mehr als Einheiten sondern als normale Worte betrachtet werden. "Die Stunde des Siegers" meint zB. ja nicht einen Zeitraum von 60 Minuten.
Als Besonderheit bei Zeitangaben gilt, daß manche Brüche - vermutlich durch den häufigen Gebrauch - ebenfalls zu eigenen Wörtern geworden sind:

zwei Zwölftel Stunden (ungebräuchlich, deshalb normaler Dezimalbruch)
zwei Viertelstunden
eine Dreiviertelstunde


*) Kleine Anmerkung nebenbei: im ersten Fall wird von den möglichen Werten einzeln - deshalb "jeder" und Singular - und im zweiten Fall von der Gesamtheit der Fälle - deshalb "alle" und Plural - gesprochen.
**) Auch hier gibt es eine Ausnahme: wenn man mit "Viertel" nämlich ein Glas Wein meint. In Österreich wird Wein nicht im Dezimalsystem ausgeschenkt, dort gibt es nicht "0.1l" oder "0.2l" sondern "Viertel" (0.25l) und "Achtel" (0.125l). In dem Fall wird dann von "Vierteln" oder "Achteln" gesprochen, die man zB. konsumiert hat.

Hast du eine Quelle und Belege für deine Antwort? Ich bezweifle das stark, was du über den Nenner als "Einheiten" sagst. Naheliegenderweise würde man in dem Ausdruck "zwei Viertel" genauso ein Substantiv im Plural sehen wie in "zwei Hälften".

Ein Verwendungsbeleg dazu: (Google) "Die Mitgliederversammlung muss den. Ausschluss mit drei Vierteln der abgegebenen gültigen Stimmen bestätigen." Hier hat man die extra Endung für den Dativ-Plural, also ist "Viertel" in "drei Viertel" tatsächlich Plural, nur dass man im Nominativ keine Endung sehen kann. Sollte das in mehr mathematischen Verwendungen der Bruchzahl anders sein?

@Alazon: Bei Google wird man so ziemlich alles und insbesondere jeden möglichen Rechtschreibfehler finden. Wenn man Einheiten tatsächlich in den Plural setzen würde, dann sollte es statt "Hundert Mann und ein Befehl" wohl "Hundert Männer und ein Befehl" heißen, oder?

Das ergoogelte Beispiel ist sicher kein Grammatikfehler. Und ich bestreite nicht, dass man "hundert Mann" sagen kann, sondern fragte, ob Brüche auf "-tel" wirklich in dieselbe Gruppe gehören.

+1 für die Antwort. Bei Einheiten wie Gramm, Meter etc. ist das alles völlig plausibel. Allerdings stimme ich der Aussage "Der Zähler hingegen legt Singular oder Plural fest" nicht zu. Z.B. halte ich drei viertel Torten für falsch und würde eine dreiviertel Torte sagen.
